# Disabling parallel jobs when calling MAKE inside a makefile

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile in which one of the targets calls another makefile elsewhere.

```
target:
    $(MAKE) -C /some/dir other_target
```

I am running my main makefile using the -j option at command line to enable parallel jobs. However, the other makefile is perhaps not written properly (it is auto-generated from a tool I am using) because it fails miserably when running with -j.

How can I stop the -j option from trickling down to the $(MAKE) command inside my main makefile?

Comment: Do you think your subdir's makefile is also called with -j option? I think no.

Comment: Yes it is. It is mentioned so in the [official documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options_002fRecursion.html#Options_002fRecursion). I tried using MAKEFLAGS=<nothing> but that still doesn't stop -j from getting passed. When I run my top level makefile without -j everything works just fine.

Comment: Khm, strange... Did you try to manually specify -j 1 for submakes?

Comment: Awesome, specifying -j 1 for submake works perfectly! Thanks a whole lot. How do I mark your comment as the answer?

Comment: Let me write a separate answer so you can mark it (-:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-j 1` option for nested `make` calls.